# PHP changing output from the database

Tags: php

I'm creating an computer inventory website that is displayed in a table.
I'm trying to change the output display for example the following

```
echo "<td>".$row['WindowsVersion']."</td>\n";
```

displays 5.0 or 5.1 or 5.2 or 6.0 or 6.1

but I want it to display

```
5.0 as 2000
5.1 as XP
5.2 as 2003
6.0 as Vista
6.1 as 7
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always create a predefined array, using the Windows version as keys like this one.

```
$win_ver = array('5.0' => '2000','5.1' => 'XP');

echo $win_ver[$row['WindowsVersion']];
```

Answer (score 6):

DB Version:

```
SELECT
    CASE WindowsVersion
    WHEN '5.0' THEN '2000'
    WHEN '5.1' THEN 'XP'
    WHEN '5.2' THEN '2003'
    WHEN '6.0' THEN 'Vista'
    ELSE '7' AS WindowsVersion
FROM ...
```

OR PHP

```
<?php
function getWinName($win) {
    switch($win) {
        case '5.0': $version = '2000'; break;
        case '5.1': $version = 'XP'; break;
        case '5.2': $version = '2003'; break;
        case '5.0': $version = 'Vista'; break;
        default: $version = '7';
    }
    return $version;
}

echo "" . getWinName($row['WindowsVersion']) . "\n";
```

Comment: Without `break` at the end of any `case` line, he outputs always '7'.

Answer (score 5):

In such cases you can use an array as display/rewrite map:

```
$rewrite = array(
  "5.0" => "2000",
  "5.1" => "XP",
  ..
);

print $rewrite[ $row['WindowsVersion'] ];
```

It simply uses your original value as an index key in the rewrite array, and gets you the associated alternative value for that.

Answer (score 4):

```
$versions = array( '5.0' => '2000',
                   '5.1' => 'XP',
                   '5.2' => '2003',
                   '6.0' => 'Vista',
                   '6.1' => '7'
                 );

if( array_key_exists( $row['WindowsVersion'], $versions ) ) {
    echo $versions[ $row['WindowsVersion'] ];
} else {
    echo $row['WindowsVersion'];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you put the things you want to see directly in the database. It would be easier.
But if this is not possible just use:

```
$map = array('5.0'=>'2000', ...);

...

print $map[$row['WindowsVersion']];
```